# How is LLVM heap value preserved after freeing?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, llvm

I am calling a C function from LLVM code, which allocates some space for a string like this: `(char *) malloc(..len..);`

This mallocated value in `%0` then stored in stack variable `%something`.

```
define i8* @someFun() {
entry:
  %something = alloca i8*, align 8
  
  ; mallocing some space for a string
  %0 = call i8* @<function-using-malloc>()
  store i8* %0, i8** %something, align 8
  
  ; freeing heap space
  %1 = call i8* @free(i8* %0)

  %2 = load i8*, i8** %something, align 8
  ret i8* %2
}
```

After the `store` instruction, I am freeing `%0` and then returning `%something` from the function.

Then after receiving the returned value from `someFun()`, the value is still available in `main()`, however I'm guessing it should have been freed?

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
    ; printing value here correctly after free
    %0 = call i8* @someFun()
    ..printing %0..
    
    ret i32 0
}
```

I'm probably missing some memory management knowledge, so my question is what happens before and after freeing `%0` in this case? Is this value gets copied from heap to stack?

Comment: Freed memory doesn't just 'go away'.  It's still there, waiting to be reused.  Accessing it, however, is undefined behaviour and the results are therefore unpredictable at best.

Comment: @PaulSanders Oh wow, then it explains this behaviour, and it's good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to read documentation about malloc/free.
This question was asked million times in C threads I guess.
Here is an example: [C - What Happens To Memory After free()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582089/c-what-happens-to-memory-after-free/18582116)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thorough then!